# Remove items from a list if it is in another list while keeping the duplicate - Python

Tags: python, list, set, list-comprehension, list-comparison

How to remove items from a list if it is in another list while keeping the duplicate?

I've succeeded by doing this but is there a faster way?

```
x = [1,2,3,4,7,7,5,6,7,8,8]
y = [1,4,5,6,8,9]
z = []
for i in x:
  if i not in y:
   z.append(i)
print z
```

Correct output:

```
[2, 3, 7, 7, 7]
```

Alternatively, a list comprehension also works but are these the only way?

```
x = [1,2,3,4,7,7,5,6,7,8,8]
y = [1,4,5,6,8,9]
z = [i for i in x if not in y]
```

Although using set is a lot faster but it doesn't keep the duplicate:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,7,7,5,6,7,8,8]
y = [1,4,5,6,8,9]
print list(set(x) - set(y))
```

The set subtraction gave the output that loses the duplicate:

```
[2, 3, 7]
```

Comment: you could use a single set for `y`.

Comment: Dominic means you can put `set_y = set(y)` outside the list comprehension so you don't create the set over and over

Comment: There's also `itertools.ifilterfalse(set(y).__contains__, x)`. It should be fairly fast.

Comment: `set_y = set(y); z = [v for v in x if v not in set_y]` shouldn't be much slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order isn't important

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,7,7,5,6,7,8,8]
>>> y = [1,4,5,6,8,9]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> count=Counter(x)
>>> for i in y:
...     del count[i]
... 
>>> list(count.elements())
[2, 3, 7, 7, 7]
```